# Card de produto com "Saiba Mais" - Quebrando

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo estes *cards* com *flexbox* pra abrir mais informações ao lado direito, mas, quando chega na última coluna, o conteúdo é quebrado. Já tentei tirar a quebra da *info* e do *card*, mas acaba sobrando um espaço em branco ou abre as informações noutra linha.

A intenção é manter 3 *cards* na linha (com a *info* aberta ao lado) e 4 *cards* sem *info* aberta. Estão em um *container flex* de `1140px`.

Até agora consegui encontrar nenhum jeito de fazer funcionar.

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const hiddenCard = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden-card');

const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

btn.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    showCard(item, index);
  })
});

const showCard = (item, index) => {
  card.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.remove('ativo');
  });

  hiddenCard.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.remove('ativo');
  });

  card[index].classList.add('ativo');
  hiddenCard[index].classList.add('ativo');
}
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
p,
a,
li,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 260px;
  height: 300px;
  background: teal;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: tomato;
  height: 200px;
  width: 260px;
}

.hidden-card {
  height: 280px;
  background: rgba(255, 100, 100, .7);
  margin-top: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade;
  width: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: .5s all;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-50px, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.hidden-card.ativo {
  transform: none;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card.ativo {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
    <a class="btn">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-card" id="hidden-card">

  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
    <a class="btn">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-card" id="hidden-card">

  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
    <a class="btn">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-card" id="hidden-card">

  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
    <a class="btn">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-card" id="hidden-card">

  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
    <a class="btn">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-card" id="hidden-card">

  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
    <a class="btn">Click</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-card" id="hidden-card">

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se está usando Bootstrap, caso esteja, ultilize as grids para repartir seu layout, ex:
OBS: expanda a tela para ver as divisões corretamente.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">
       Card title
      </h5>
      <div class="card-body">
       <p class="card-text">
        Card content
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
       Card footer
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">
       Card title
      </h5>
      <div class="card-body">
       <p class="card-text">
        Card content
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
       Card footer
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">
       Card title
      </h5>
      <div class="card-body">
       <p class="card-text">
        Card content
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
       Card footer
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">
       Card title
      </h5>
      <div class="card-body">
       <p class="card-text">
        Card content
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
       Card footer
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">
       Card title
      </h5>
      <div class="card-body">
       <p class="card-text">
        Card content
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
       Card footer
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">
       Card title
      </h5>
      <div class="card-body">
       <p class="card-text">
        Card content
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
       Card footer
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">
       Card title
      </h5>
      <div class="card-body">
       <p class="card-text">
        Card content
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
       Card footer
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Já tentei, o problema continua, só aumenta o tamanho do container :(